# Nestjs Subscriber +TypeOrm Injection through yml files

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

How can we inject connection dependencies of the subscriber with yml files .

my files are :
ormconfig.yml

```
default:
    type: 'postgres'
    host: 'localhost'
    port: 5432
    username: 'postgres'
    password: 'root'
    database: 'hiring_db'
    entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
    synchronize: true
    logging: ["query","error"]
    logger: "file"
    extra: { timezone: "+5:30" }
    migrations: ["src/migrations/*.ts"]
    cli:   {
        migrationDir: 'src/migrations'
    }
    subscribers: ["src/**/*.subscriber{.ts,.js}"]
```

JobPostingModule.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JobPostingController } from './job-posting.controller';
import { JobPostingService } from './job-posting.service';
import { AuthModule } from '../auth/auth.module';
import { RecruitmentService } from '../recruitment/recruitment.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule
  ],
  controllers: [JobPostingController],
  providers: [JobPostingService, RecruitmentService]
})
export class JobPostingModule {}
```

JobSubscriber.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Jobs } from 'src/entities/job-posting.entity';
import { Connection, EntitySubscriberInterface, getConnection, InsertEvent, UpdateEvent } from 'typeorm';
import { JobPostingService } from './job-posting.service';


@Injectable()
export class JobSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {
  
  constructor(private readonly connection: Connection) {
    connection.subscribers.push(this); // <---- THIS 
   
}

  listenTo() {
    return Jobs;
  }

  afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<Jobs>) {
    console.log('Hi guys!');
  };

  afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<any>) {
    console.log('Hi guys!');
  }

}
```

I am getting this error Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JobSubscriber (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

```
Potential solutions:
- If Connection is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If Connection is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Connection */ ]
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use `subscribers: ["src/**/*.subscriber{.ts,.js}"]`

just add `connection.subscribers.push(this);` logic

and use the subscriber as a module Provider.

Answer (score -1):

[You can refer to the official NestJS documentation for this problem.](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#typeorm-integration)

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Once you imported the `TypeOrmModule` you can use `Connection` as a provider everywhere.

Comment: After your solution I am getting this  TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer to better solve the problem.